# how to stop watching changes to a particular variable in model in swiftui

Tags: ios, mvvm, swiftui, mutating-function

I have a model and I have a deck variable . Now I want to remove twelve items from deck array . However the model is changing for every item I removed , I want the view to change only after twelve cards are removed.function getTwelveCards is getting run continuously and all the cards are removed. The required functionality is to remove only twelve cards Here is my model :

```
struct SetGame<Color, Shape, Shadings> {
    
    var deck : Array<SetCard>
    var addedTwelveCards = false
    
    func printCardCount() {
        print("card count: \(deck.count)")
    }
    
    mutating func getASetCard() -> SetCard {
            deck.remove(at: 0)
        
    }
    
    mutating func getTwelveCards() -> Array<SetGame<Color, Shape, Shadings>.SetCard> {
        var cards : Array<SetGame<Color, Shape, Shadings>.SetCard> = []
        if deck.count >= 12 && !addedTwelveCards{
            for _ in 1...12 {
                cards.append(getASetCard())
            }
        }
        addedTwelveCards = true
        return cards
    }
    
    
    struct SetCard : Identifiable {
        var color : Color
        var shapeName : ShapeName
        var shading : Shadings
        var count : Int
        var id = UUID()
        
    }
}
```

Here is my ViewModel :

```
class SetGameViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published private var setGameModel = SetGame<Color, ShapeName, Shadings>(deck: createSetGameDeck())
    
    
    static let colors = [Color.red, Color.green, Color.blue]
    static let shapes = [ShapeName.Capsule, ShapeName.Circle, ShapeName.Square]
    static let shadings = [Shadings.fill, Shadings.striped, Shadings.stroked]
    
    
     
    static  func createSetGameDeck() -> Array<SetGame<Color, ShapeName, Shadings>.SetCard> {
        var deck : Array<SetGame<Color, ShapeName, Shadings>.SetCard> = []
        
            for color in colors {
                for shape in shapes {
                    for shading in shadings {
                        for count in 1...3 {
                            let setCard = SetGame<Color, ShapeName, Shadings>.SetCard(color: color, shapeName: shape, shading: shading, count: count)
                            deck.append(setCard)
                        }
                        
                    }
                }
            }
          deck.shuffle()
        print("\(deck.count)")
          return deck
        }
        
    // MARK: Intents
    
    func getCardCount() {
        setGameModel.printCardCount()
    }
    
    var deck : Array<SetGame<Color, ShapeName, Shadings>.SetCard> {
        get {
            
            setGameModel.deck
        }
    }
    
    var addedTwelveCards : Bool {
        self.setGameModel.addedTwelveCards
    }
    
    var getFirstTwelveSetCards : Array<SetGame<Color, ShapeName, Shadings>.SetCard> {
        print("new deck count: \(self.setGameModel.deck.count)")
        return self.setGameModel.getTwelveCards()
      
    }
    
    
}
```

Here is my View:

```
struct SetGameView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var setGameViewModel : SetGameViewModel
    
    var body: some View {
        Group {
            if !setGameViewModel.addedTwelveCards {
            Grid(self.setGameViewModel.getFirstTwelveSetCards) { setCard in
                       SetCardView(shapeName: setCard.shapeName, shading: setCard.shading, color: setCard.color, count: setCard.count)
                   }
            }
        }
       
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Make sure that the getter `getFirstTwelveSetCards` doesn't actually modify your view model. Otherwise, every time the value is read, you have a side effect of actually changing a property of the view model, which is a `@Published` property, so that causes the observed object to change, which causes the view to be recreated, which starts the cycle again

Comment: I added removing 12 cards from deck to init() that solved it.Thanks for explaining everything clearly